# error when trying to use NFS with laravel homestead and virtualbox

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

Laravel/homestead version: 9.3.0
VirtualBox version: 6.0
Vagrant version: 2.2.6

i'm trying to use NFS with laravel/homestead per project setup. i used to have all projects within same homestead environment, but changed it to per projects yesterday. 
All sites is working fine when NOT using nfs. (except from being really slow)

I've installed Vagrant WinNFSd.

the error is:

```
==> bpa: Exporting NFS shared folders...
==> bpa: Preparing to edit nfs mounting file.
[NFS] Status: halted
[NFS] Start: started
==> bpa: Mounting NFS shared folders...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o vers=3,udp,actimeo=1,nolock 192.168.10.1:/D/SynologyDrive/Prosjekter/Privat/bpa /home/vagrant/code

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

i've searched google and tried everything without luck.

the setup:

```
folders:
    -
        map: 'path\to\project'
        to: /home/vagrant/code
        type: "nfs"
```